# Possible hardware fix for screen flickering laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hardware-failure

any technician here? What could be the potential hardware issue based on the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/110d3OWhECCuczguQ905yZk7aGdGWsmJy/view?fbclid=IwAR2e9m7jY43mp0RTerKR0zYjoahgTuen4UUncwVJx4_jgXGUToecDimRDms) (I noticed that there are part in which was not completely affected/not flickering). It started as a minor flick but now it got worse, I know its hardware issue because even in Bios mode and startup boot, it starts to flicker. What is the possible fix of potential hardware issue? The GPU temperature is fine so I think its not the GPU dying (its only 2 years old). This is the minor [flick](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10QLM8-kMzQqq7l1cfefEe2K2Wng9TXBM/view) before the recent one. My model is Acer Nitro 5 An515-44. I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: What happens when you attach a monitor to the HDMI-out port?

Comment: Looks like EMI based on the background noise.Have you considered taking it to a trained technician?

Comment: Sadly. I dont have monitor, but I tried connecting it wirelessly in lg smart tv, and theres no screen flickering (I dont know if that can be alternative for monitor)

Comment: I dont take it yet to technician, because of fearing that the technician will just replace the part rather than actual solving it, I don't have money for replacement right now, and I'm a Computer Science student so I'm using it everyday and heavily rely with it.